# How to use thumbnail as buttongroups in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For eg:- A, B and C are thumbnails. So that when thumbnail "A" i show "A" as      selected (similar to button pressed in button group) and display some information  associated with thumbnail "A" in div.

Comment: wow, you really need to be more descriptive than that

Comment: consider three thumbnails are next to each other like "A  B  C" in a row. Consider the following link:-http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

Answer (score 1):

*Button groups* only refers to the appearance of several button together.

If you want to use the Twitter Bootstrap button plugin for thumbnails, and simulate radio buttons, it seems possible :

Add this `data-toggle="buttons-radio"` to some common parent, and activate the plugin with something like this :

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    $(this).button('toggle');
});
```

You can change the appearance with some css :

```css
a .text { display: none; }
a.active .text { display: block; }
```

HTML :

```html
<ul class="thumbnails" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail active">
            <img data-src="holder.js/260x180" alt="" />
            <span class="text">A</span>
        </a>

    </li>
<!-- ... -->
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3Vrms/)

In theory, you should be able to use this with any element, not just `<a>`